# Why are the text formatting tags different in a comment than to a question/answer?

Tags: support, design, formatting

In a question/answer, the **Bold** tags are 2x asterisks:

```
**Bold**
```

And *Italics* is a single asterisk:

```
*Italics*
```

However, in the comment fields, why are they different?

*Sorry. I previously had single asterisks below. Infact, it should have been double.*

Double asterisk for **Bold**:

```
**Bold**
```

And underscore for *Italics*.

```
_Italics_
```

I sometimes get confused and commenting and/or writing a question/answer.

EDIT: So, I got this info from the 'help' buttons. In the question/answer help icon, it automatically used asterisks only.

However, in the 'help' of the comments, it states to use underscore:

[image: Screenshot of 'help' in comments.]

I have just always followed the 'help' buttons.

Comment: *I'm just testing something.* **Because I'd never noticed this before.** ...yeah, that first sentence is `*like this*` and the second is `**like this**`. Not sure what you're talking about here.

Comment: So @AbbyT.Miller Do you know what I'm talking about now? I got this info from the 'help' buttons. Maybe they aren't that helpful after all.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not sure what you're asking for. What's written in the help text for commenting works, does it not? `**Bold**` and `_italics_` written thusly are mini-markdown convention. Having it also work `*this way*` for italics is just a bonus, I think.

Comment: I didn't ask "Why does it work?", I asked why is it different. Now, of course, it has been answered we know that either cases work. Remember, you made this comment before it was answered. I _thought_ the help info was set in stone, but now I **know** it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the case. Stack Exchange follows the [normal Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em) in both cases:

```
Emphasis

Markdown treats asterisks (*) and underscores (_) as indicators of
emphasis. Text wrapped with one * or _ will be wrapped with an HTML
<em> tag; double *’s or _’s will be wrapped with an HTML <strong>
tag.

E.g., this input:

*single asterisks*

_single underscores_

**double asterisks**

__double underscores__

will produce:

<em>single asterisks</em>

<em>single underscores</em>

<strong>double asterisks</strong>

<strong>double underscores</strong>

You can use whichever style you prefer; the lone restriction is that
the same character must be used to open and close an emphasis span.
```

Basically, **double** of **either character** is bold, and *single* of *either character* is italics.

Comment: And in comments:  __double__ of **either character** is bold, and _single_ of _either character_ is italics.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I've always just followed the help info. I've updated my answer because I can't add photos in comments. Also, I've never tested double or single of anything.